# could not create ssl/tls secure channel nginx

Tags: nginx

i have a structure like this
client-nginx(2-upstream)-windows servers
there is one service when the client reguest the service i get an error
the request was aborted could not create ssl/tls secure channel

when I connect directly there is no error

---

nginx-conf
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWOOA.png)